# iptables put external ip to internal machines

Tags: iptables

Cant wrap my mind on this problem. I want to put external ip to internal machines ("LAN").

```
            200.0.0.1               /-->[eth0 s2] 200.0.0.2
[internet]<---->[eth0 s1 eth1]<--[sw]-->[eth0 s3] 200.0.0.3
                                    \-->[eth0 s4] 200.0.0.4
```

I want to be able to ping s2,s3,s4 from internet and internet from s2,s3,s4. I don't want to set many ip 200.0.0.2,200.0.0.3,200.0.0.4 on [eth0 s1] then SNAT/DNAT it to internal ip.

Is it possible to do that?

Do i need to set something like promiscuous mode on [eth0 s1]?

Comment: It pretty heavily depends on address space you got from your ISP.  Easiest would be to put a publicly routable subnet behind the router, and configure routes.

Comment: Thank you for input, i will rethink it tomorrow.